# Как обрабатывать такие ошибки?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/1t7rw1b0/) моего кода:

```
try {
    //Тут другой код который может вызвать ошибку
    setTimeout(()=>{
    throw new Error('Тестовая ошибка!');
  },1);
} catch (e) {
    alert('Ошибка: '+e.name + ":" + e.message);
}
```

Как отловить ошибку вызванную в обработчике setTimeout ?

Comment: обернуть в try...catch тело функции в setTimeout. По другому никак

Comment: другими словами, перетащить try-catch внутрь

Comment: вам интересна конкретна эта конструкция или как вообще ошибки в асинхронном коде обрабатывать?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, намекаешь на Promise?

Comment: @Grundy как вариант

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, как вообще в асинхронном коде

Comment: @Mr_Epic, ну довольно часто это делается с помощью reject коллбека внутри Promise если вкратце

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, был бы благодарен, если бы оформиле в виде ответа, подробно расписав этот метод

Comment: @Mr_Epic, мне сейчас лень) Про промисы Вы можете чуть подробнее почитать в этом ответе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554291/14963

Comment: И вот здесь: http://learn.javascript.ru/promise. Основной смысл в том что есть сахар для асинхронных операций и в нем есть своя штука типа-throw